# Apache camel continue in splitter

Tags: apache-camel, continue, splitter

I'm pretty new in camel, sorry if this question is stupid but lets say I have a camel splitter which iterates over some objects from the database. I'd like to ask if there is something like continue in camel splitter. Let's say I have an array of numbers like {1,2,3,4} in a body and I want to print numbers, but I don't want to print number 3. I know I can use choose but in some cases continue would be a better option. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would use [Message Filter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html), either with `filter(Predicate)` or `stop()`

**Using `filter`:**

```
from("direct:filter3")
    .split(body())
    .filter(body().isNotEqualTo(3))
    .to("log:splitted");
```

**Using `stop`:**

```
from("direct:stop3")
    .split(body())
    .choice().when(body().isEqualTo(3)).stop().end()
    .to("log:splitted");
```

Comment: @Bedia thank you for your answer. I have a question. when I use stop it sometimes stop whole route, even if I am in a splitter. Don't you know when stop() stop whole route and when only actual message? Thank you.

Comment: I have never seen this behavior. When using splitter, Camel creates new Exchange for every split. When you use `stop`, it marks current Exchange as done with property `Exchange.ROUTE_STOP`. This should not be propagated outside of Splitter. Maybe you are using custom Aggregator and you have propagated there `Exchange.ROUTE_STOP` property to parent exchange. Or you have used it in different context, because Consumer, Endpoint, CamelContext, Service... All of these classes have its `stop` method, but with different purpose.

Comment: You are absolutely perfect, I had custom Aggregator and when my route found only one item in the database and I called stop on this item in splitter my aggregation copy newExchange to the oldExchange and this stop was propagated outside of the splitter. Thank you very much.